# Search bar open in chrome unlock device mobile in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome

I am facing UX issue when the user locks device on the product listing page then returns to browsing a search page. It opens the search bar by default.

This is ReactJs base project and this only appears on Android mobile using chrome browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the after investigation and this issue already exists in Mobify.
`https://www.merlinspotions.com/`

Thanks.